# Extractin p.values from a replicated cor.test

Tags: r

I have performed a correlation test to a randomized set of variables.

replicate(1000, cor.test(sample(v1),sample(v2)))

I would like to obtain the p.values from each test in a vector for further analysis, how can I do so?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need the p values of the replications you can just index it in the replications. `replicate` will simplify the results in an array (vector here) by default:

```
replicate(1000, cor.test(sample(rnorm(100)),sample(rnorm(100)))$p.value)
```